# Are there optimal sizes for an Hashtbl in OCaml?

Tags: performance, ocaml

Say I need to store 20 keys/values, would it be more efficient to use a power of 2, e.g. 32? I read a paper where the authors used a size of 251 (for an unknown number of keys/values), is this just a random number, or is there some reasoning behind it?

I’m talking about the `n` in `Hashtbl.create n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Since you ask about `Hashtbl` by name, I assume you're talking about the standard hash table module. This module always allocates tables in power-of-2 sizes. So you don't have to worry about it.

There are two basic "extra good" sizes for hash tables. Powers of two are good because they make it easy to find your hash bucket. The last step of a hashing procedure is take the hash value modulo the size of your table. If the table size is a power of two, this modulo operation can be done very quickly with a masking operation. I'm not sure this matters in today's world, unless your hash function itself is very fast to compute.

The second good value is a prime number. A prime number is good because it tends to spread values throughout the table. If you have hash values that happen to be predominantly a multiple of some number, this will cause dense clusters in the hash table unless the hash table size is relatively prime to the predominant number. A large-ish prime number is relatively prime to virtually everything, so it prevents clustering. So, 251 is good because it's a prime number.

Comment: Thank you, I’m talking about the `n` in `Hashtbl.create n`.

Comment: Hashtbl rounds this up to the next power of 2 internally. So, just pick any reasonable number near the largest size you expect to have most of the time.

Comment: Jeffrey, you are right, hashtable sizes are now rounded up to the power of two, but this is new. The way I remember the old hashtables, they started exactly the size specified by the programmer and if grown, the new size was computed as 2*old_size+1.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I just checked the 4.00.0 sources (which I happen to have handy).